# iframe width is not proper on slider page but on other pages its working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I using a WordPress theme and that theme have its own slider.
and i am using an iframe in footer section to show a image this iframe image width is proper with other pages but its not proper on first slider page.
please help me to resolve this.
when we hover on bottom footer images like semiconductor oil and gas then a frame show on page.
This is the slier page link where its not working: http://indodeshost.com/uhp/
this is the page link where its working properly:  http://indodeshost.com/uhp/semiconductor/

Thank you

Comment: can you help me to come out with this problem

Comment: I guess, its just a width and height issue, just set the size similar to that in the slider.

Comment: Can you post your codes

Comment: i only write down the frame code but i didn't write the theme slider codes its theme functionality.

Comment: No its not width height issues you can try to change width and height using inspect element but it will not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82663/discussion-between-ganpat-kakar-and-the-well).